# Array undefined on map and subscribe Ionic 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

I creted a service that I want to get data from a JSON file and assign to an array (countries) to use at entire application (a lots of Pages), but when I call getCountries method, the countries is undefined, what is wrong at my approach?

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class CountryService {

private countries: any;
private isLoaded: boolean;
private url: string = 'http://localhost:8100/assets/data/countriesV2.json';

constructor(private http: Http) {
    if (!this.isLoaded) {
        this.http.get(this.url)
            .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe(result => { 
                this.countries = result;
            });
        this.isLoaded = true;
    }
}

public getCountries() {
    console.log(this.countries);
    return this.countries();
}
}
```

Comment: First of all, make sure if the data is, in fact, successfully retrieved using your broswer's developer tools. If you are using chrome, network tab shows the requests

Answer (score 0):

Maybe changing `return this.countries();` to `return this.countries;` may help

Also, check that your result is not empty :

```
.subscribe(result => { 
     this.countries = result;
     console.log(result)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always map the data in the service, and subscribe in your component. The reason why `this.countries` is undefined because it IS undefined, even though you are trying to do the request in the constructor, it's not going to work. Change your service to this:

```
@Injectable()
export class CountryService {

  private url: string = 'http://localhost:8100/assets/data/countriesV2.json';

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  public getCountries() {
    this.http.get(this.url)
      .map(res => res.json())  
  }
}
```

And then in your components you call `getCountries` and subscribe to the request.

```
countries: any[] = [];

constructor(private countryService: CountryService) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.countryService.getCountries()
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.countries = data;
      // here countries is not undefined, so call your "randomCountry" method here!
      this.getRandomCountry();
    });
}
```

Since this is an async operation, I suggest you use the safe navigation operator in that view, that does not try to show the property of country in case country is null. More info [**here**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator). So the usage would be:

```
<div *ngFor="let country of countries">
  {{country?.yourProperty}} // replace "yourProperty" with your actual property
</div>
```

Some more detailed explanations about HTTP here from the [**official docs**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html)

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I've made the changes but still not working, at my page, the countries still undefined:

    ``

Comment: You need to call your method `getRandomCountry` inside the the subscription where country will not be undefined! Check my updated answer :)